# EXT4 error loading journal in NAS server

Tags: mount, nas, ext4

My NAS server is recently refusing to mount an external USB drive:

```
root@MyCloudEX2Ultra root # mount -r -t ext4 /dev/sdc1 tmp/
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc1,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so

root@MyCloudEX2Ultra root # dmesg | tail   
JBD2: Unrecognised features on journal
EXT4-fs (sdc1): error loading journal
```

It does mount fine with the option `-o noload` passed to `mount`.

I tried running `e2fsck` on it from the NAS server, and disabling journal (even though I'm not so sure what that means), but apparently my NAS server doesn't have a recent version of `e2fsck`:

```
root@MyCloudEX2Ultra root # e2fsck /dev/sdc1
e2fsck 1.42.9 (28-Dec-2013)
/dev/sdc1 has unsupported feature(s): metadata_csum
e2fsck: Get a newer version of e2fsck!

root@MyCloudEX2Ultra root # tune2fs -O ^has_journal /dev/sdc1
tune2fs 1.42.9 (28-Dec-2013)
tune2fs: Filesystem has unsupported read-only feature(s) while trying to open /dev/sdc1
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
```

This drive has been mounted several times in the same NAS server. Also, the drive is mounting perfectly fine in another machine with Linux Mint and passes `e2fsck` tests:

```
(base) ➜  ~ sudo e2fsck -vf /dev/sdc1                                                                                            [19:27:07]
e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information

      196412 inodes used (0.16%, out of 122101760)
       16294 non-contiguous files (8.3%)
          52 non-contiguous directories (0.0%)
             # of inodes with ind/dind/tind blocks: 0/0/0
             Extent depth histogram: 196013/391
   283636698 blocks used (58.08%, out of 488378368)
           0 bad blocks
          13 large files

      187435 regular files
        8968 directories
           0 character device files
           0 block device files
           0 fifos
           0 links
           0 symbolic links (0 fast symbolic links)
           0 sockets
------------
      196403 files
```

By the way:

```
root@MyCloudEX2Ultra root # uname -a
Linux MyCloudEX2Ultra 3.10.39 #1 SMP Thu Aug 29 20:35:52 PDT 2019 2014T30p5 Build-gitad56653 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Anyone knows how to fix this problem? Since it is a NAS server (WD MyCloud EX2 Ultra), I cannot make changes to it, so I'd rather modify the USB drive somehow in another computer.

Comment: Why are you trying to disable `has_journal` when the system complains about `metadata_csum`? Were you planning to downgrade the disk to ext2?

Comment: Because system error message says problem w journal, and mounting it with `noload` (journal) works. But I’m in unfamiliar ground here. I’d rather keep it as ext4 if possible sinceit used to work. But if ext2 is the way I’ll do it. This is a back drive for the NAS.